# Herança ou Dependência?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, herança, libcurl

Bom, minha pergunta é o seguinte. Estou refatorando um sistema onde tenho uma integração com uma API REST, existe uma classe chamada `Marketplace` (Que faz as consultas a API) a qual atualmente estendo da classe `Curl` (Que é uma interface simplificada para o curl do PHP).

A questão é, a classe `Marketplace` deveria mesmo ser estendida de da classe  `Curl` ou talvez `Curl` deveria ser uma dependência da classe `Marketplace`?

Classe `Marketplace` atual estendida (Ilustrativa e simplificada...)

```
<?php
class Marketplace extends Curl
{
    public function getOffers()
    {
        $this->get('/marketplace/offers');

        return $this->getResponseBody();
    }
}
```

Ou `Marketplace` com dependência

```
<?php
class Marketplace
{
    private $_curl;

    public function __construct(Curl $curl)
    {
        $this->_curl = $curl;
    }

    public function getOffers()
    {
        $this->_curl->get('/marketplace/offers');

        return $this->_curl->getResponseBody();
    }
}
```

Qual seria, digamos uma estrutura melhor? E se possível o porque..

Comment: Pergunte-se: `MarketPlace` adiciona funcionalidades à classe `Curl` ou apenas a necessita para funcionar?

Comment: De fato ela não acrescentará novas funcionalidades a `Curl`.

Comment: Então a melhor escolha neste caso seja a dependência, certo?

Comment: Exatamente. Pelos os exemplos que você mostrou, é somente uma dependência. Mas não quer dizer que, caso teu sistema venha a crescer, `MarketPlace` não estenda uma classe que poderá vir entre essa e a `Curl`.

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar alguma resposta como resolvida. Sua dúvida hoje pode ser a de outra pessoa amanhã. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Vendo pelo lado da coesão e do acoplamento, que é um dos pontos chave da [Injeção de Dependência](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuxHv3YkQSQ), eu prefiro tornar `Curl` uma dependência de `Marketplace`, assim você terá uma melhor coesão, um baixo acomplamento o que vai gerar um melhor nível de encapsulamento.

Penso assim porque `Curl` tem características suficientes para torna-se um objeto (componente) encapsulado, então `Marketplace` vai utiliza-lo como uma dependência. Uma grande vantagem é que se no futuro a comunicação de `Marketplace` não for mais via `Curl`, você poderá criar uma interface com os métodos que devem ser implementados e aplica-la em `Curl` e na nova classe a ser criada.

Outro ponto importante é que conforme `Marketplace` crescer, ela poderá quebrar o [Princípio da substituição de Liskov](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princ%C3%ADpio_da_substitui%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Liskov), por falar nele, recomendo que você leia sobre os [Princípios SOLID](http://code.tutsplus.com/pt/tutorials/solid-part-1-the-single-responsibility-principle--net-36074), são fundamentos muito legais para um desenvolvimento ágil e um código legível.

Comment: Obrigado Marcio, e obrigado pelas referências, será de grande ajuda!

Comment: @CaioCésar, Imagina! Fico contente em ajudar! Continue assim que você está no caminho certo!

Answer (score 2):

Essa é uma pergunta comum à quem começa a trabalhar com Orientação a Objetos. E, pra piorar, muita gente tenta explicar, mas acaba complicando tanto a explicação que a emenda acaba pior que o soneto.

Quando na dúvida sobre quando estender uma classe, usar uma interface (crédito extra) ou injetar outra vinda de uma objeto, você deve se perguntar se seu objeto **é** uma determinada coisa, se ele **pode ser** uma determinada tal coisa (além dele mesmo) ou ele **apenas precisa** de uma determinada coisa para funcionar.

- Se você responder que um objeto **é** uma outra coisa, você aplica uma herança.
- Se você responder que seu objeto **pode ser** alguma outra coisa além dele mesmo, implemente uma interface. Mesmo vazia, elas servem como tipos, o que é ótimo para polimorfismo.
- Se você responder que seu objeto **apenas precisa** de um outro, injete-o como dependência.

No seu caso em particular, *Marketplace* **não é** um objeto *Curl*, mas ele **pode ser**, então você deveria ter uma interface.

Eu sugeriria, porém, algo mais subjetivo, pois os dados podem vir de qualquer lugar, seja local, de um banco de dados, seja remoto. E se remoto, pode-se usar Curl ou *Stream Sockets*:

```
interface OffersDataAccess {

    public function getOffers();
}

class Marketplace implements OffersDataAccess {

    public function getOffers() {}
}
```

E quem for usar essa classe recebe um *OffersDataAccess* que pode ser um *Marketplace* como também pode ser um *Catalog* (Catálogo de Ofertas), um *CommercialBreak* (intervalo comercial) ou mesmo um *OutdoorAnnouncement* (outdoor):

```
class Catalog implements OffersDataAccess {

    public function getOffers() {}
}

class CommercialBreak implements OffersDataAccess {

    public function getOffers() {}
}

class OffersController {

    public function listOffers( OffersDataAccess $offers ) {

        return $offers -> getOffers();
    }
}

class OutdoorAnnouncement  {

    public function listOffers( OffersDataAccess $offers ) {

        return $offers -> getOffers();
    }
}

$controller = new OffersController;

$marketPlaceOffers         = $controller -> listOffers( new Marketplace );
$catalogOffers             = $controller -> listOffers( new Catalog );
$commercialBreakOffers     = $controller -> listOffers( new CommercialBreak );
$outdoorAnnouncementOffers = $controller -> listOffers( new OutdoorAnnouncement );
```

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, acho que consegui entender melhor sobre esta questão aplicando as perguntas. Então creio se eu tivesse vários `Marketplaces` (Ex: `Extra`, `Walmart`) eles poderiam estender da mesma (Classe `Marketpace`) assim seriam novos objetos, estou certo?

Comment: Sim e não, tudo dependeria da magnitude da aplicação. Se você tiver vários *Marketplace*s que compartilhem características (propriedades) e/ou ações (métodos) então sim, caberia criar uma clase abstrata com tudo que eles teriam em comum, implementar a interface nela e todos estenderiam essa super-class (e consequentemente a interface). Se não houver ganho significativo na abstração, você não deve fazer pois estaria apenas inflingindo *Syntatic Sugar* na sua Aplicação.